# Prevent a NestedScrollView from scrolling

Tags: flutter

I have a widget that is a NestedScrollView and some text in the body. There are cases where I want to "lock" the user and not allow him to scroll. I have tried using the physics property and set it to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()as the docs seem to indicate this is what it is for: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html however this does not seem to be working and the screen still scrolls.

Is there a way to prevent the scroll?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 150.0,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                forceElevated: true,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text('I am a header'),
                ),
              )
            ];
          },
          body: Text(' I am scrolling'),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: I'm currently encountering this same issue, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: me too! did you solve it?

Comment: Have you tried `shrinkWrap: true`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Widget as a parent for your SliverAppBar

```
         SliverOverlapAbsorber(  
         handle:NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
         sliver: Child(),
         )
```

Sample Code

```
     NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool  
         innerBoxIsScrolled) { 
        return <Widget>[
          SliverOverlapAbsorber( 
         handle:NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
            sliver: SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 150.0,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              forceElevated: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text('I am a header'),
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: const TabBarView(
        children: [],
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a widget called `AbsorbPointer`. Wrap it around your `NestedScrollView`.

```
AbsorbPointer( 
   isAbsorbing: true,
   child: NestedScrollView(...))
```